# Change Icons and a title of the installed application on Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, installation, desktop

I have an unusual requirement, I need to change the brand of the application on the fly. The scenario is like this:

1. A user downloads the application from a site branded 'A'
2. When he logins to my app it appears that his account is associated with brand 'B'
3. I need to switch installed application to the same feel and look as if it was downloaded from site 'B'
4. The application will contain everything needed for multiple brands

Is it possible or I am looking at the wall here?

Note: the application is in C# .NET Core 6